# Vertical Tabs: Removing UL & DIV Break Without jQuery Or Fixed Position Property

Tags: javascript, css, tabs, html-lists

There are different ways for you to create navigational tabs. Horizontal tabs are easy, but vertical tabs are a different monster.

If you've ever tried to create a vertical navigation tab, you may have come across a situation during coding where a break is inserted between the UL and DIV tags. I am trying to remove that break so that the UL and DIV tags are in the same line, and I know that there's a CSS code that can do this, but I don't know which.

I tried using `white-space: nowrap`. It only works on texts, not elements.

I tried the float: left and right with forced margin and width as suggested in a question here on SO. That failed, too.

My only other options are to force the fixes by:

1) Using position: fixed with manual top and left numbers

2) Putting the UL and DIV tags inside a TABLE

3) Use jQuery

I want to avoid using all those three for the time being.

You can view my demo by clicking here: http://www.wammyradio.com/personal/stackexchange/testing.html

In this demonstration, the line break is being represented by the HR tag.

What is the proper code for me to use so that the UL and DIV elements are on the same line (ie, next to each other, above the HR line), and there is no break between them?

Comment: if you give a fiddle, this is a 2min solution... hint : use `inline-block` on wrapper div! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this if with clearfix::

```
ul.tabs {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10%;
}
div.tabcontents {
    border: 2px solid violet;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

or else use `display:inline-block; in place of float:left and vertical-align:top;` in ul.tabs..but if you use inline-block some space will come in between the ul and div

Comment: Using `float` obstructs the outside black lines, but the `display:inline-block` works. What I wanted was the two items to stay inside the black border without breaking through or overlapping. That technique worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `<hr>` element.
2. Add `display: inline-block;` to both the `<div class="tabcontents">` and `<ul class="tabs">` elements.
3. That's all.